# scoped variable set to userid after authenticating sessionId not available inside hub in signalr

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I'm trying to authenticate my client by resolving `sessionId` to `userId` and set it in a scoped object. The code is able to authenticate and I'm setting the `userid` to the scoped object, but when I try to access this scoped object from Hub using DI, I'm not getting the scoped object rather a new object.

This method of authenticating is working for APIs.

My authenticator code

```
protected Scope Scope; // this is a custom class that stores userId along with some other params.

    public AuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock,
        Scope Scope)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
        this.Scope = Scope;
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        Task<AuthenticateResult> Result = null;
        Task<AuthenticateResult> Failure = Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("not authorized"));

        try
        {
            var session = await GetSessionDetails(input);

            if (session == null)
            {
                return await Failure;
            }

            string Name = session.UserId;

            Scope.UserId = new Guid(session.UserId); //setting userid during authenticaion here.
            Result = Task.FromResult(
                AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(Principal, AuthSchemeName)));
        }
        catch
        {
            Result = Failure;
        }

        // refresh token goes here
        return await Result;
    }
```

My hub code

```
public class DashboardHub : Hub
{
    private readonly Scope ThisScope;

    public DashboardHub(Scope scope)
    {
        ThisScope = scope; //scope.UserId is coming as Guid.Default which means that my change in authentication is not coming here.
    }
    
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        //ThisScope.UserId // will map it to Context.connectionId but its coming as Guid.Default
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
}
```

My startup

```
// Here I add the scoped object where UserID is initially null but set during authentication.
services.AddScoped (sp => new Scope (TheConfig, logger, Clock));
```

Comment: Did you put the [Authorize] attribute on your hub class?

Comment: @Brennan yes ofcourse. its HandleAuthenticateAsync of this [Authorize] attribute only which is setting scope. when i debug i can see the flow going inside the HandleAuthenticateAsync method when i continue and flow reaches inside hub method OnConnectedAsync its again set to Guid.Default.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 independent scopes at play here:

- The request scope
- The hub invocation scope

They are different and your request scoped services are different instances that what gets injected into the hub (put a break point in the DI callback and see the scope object get newly created before the hub is constructed).

In this particular case, you should just use the claims principal, that flows to the hub via the HubCallerContext.User;